# Install hangs on reboot, Virtualbox 4.2.16, Ubuntu 12.04 Guest on Windows 7 Host

Tags: 12.04, installation, windows-7, virtualbox

I am a Linux noob. I am trying to set up a VM so I can learn to program in C (I hear Linux is the best platform to do that on).

I have successfully installed Ubuntu 12.04 Guest on one Win 7 Host (VBox 4.2.16) and I have failed on two Win 7 Hosts with the same symptom: the install gets as far as this screen:

[image: Installation problem]

Okay, anyway, the install gets that far but then the VM stops responding. Confirmed that virtual CD is not in the virtual drive. I press ENTER but nothing happens. I have waited maybe 30 mins, tried again, still nothing. Again, this same result has occurred over multiple attempts with two different Win 7 hosts.

The only common thread that I can see between the two failed installs is that both Win 7 machines are laptops, whereas the successful install occurred on a desktop. I know, that is a weak correlation. I wondered if the touchpad peripherals confuse it for some reason? Shot in the dark.

Any help would be **much** appreciated. I am now thinking of trying a different flavor of Linux or perhaps a different VM (e.g. Windows Virtual PC). Will try to remember to post a followup if I can do that successfully.

Again thanks in advance for any help.

I should add, in case it is not clear: the screen shown in the screen capture is after the install has completed. The VM booted up from virtual CD and went through the install just fine. But at this final stage the thing hangs. I have "force shutdowned" the VM and then rebooted, but on occasion I get an error like "broken pipe" and frankly I do not want to deal with the possibility of a 99% completed OS install where there's some slim chance of some catastrophic system error occurring at some point, hosing my system. However, reassurances would be welcome...

-Adam

Comment: I should add, in case it is not clear: the screen shown in the screen capture is *after* the install has completed. The VM booted up from virtual CD and went through the install just fine. But at this final stage the thing hangs. I have "force shutdowned" the VM and then rebooted, but on occasion I get an error like "broken pipe" and frankly I do not want to deal with the possibility of a 99% completed OS install where there's some slim chance of some catastrophic system error occurring at some point, hosing my system. However, reassurances would be welcome...

Comment: The screenshot you provided is **clearly at the end of the shutdown process after booting the .iso **. Please identify the version of Ubuntu you are trying to boot, completely shut down the guest, make sure the .ios is not in the CD drive, and reboot. Post an updated screenshot or error message.

Comment: Also , as it appears your questions are more about running Virtualbox in a Windows host, rather then with Ubuntu itself, you might have better luck on the virtualbox forums. https://forums.virtualbox.org/

Answer (score 2):

You can safely do an "unclean shutdown" (either close the window and choose "Power off the machine", or click the "Machine" menu and then "Close"), because the filesystems are unmounted. When a filesystem is unmounted, you're sure that there's nothing left to be written.

Comment: OP here. Thanks very much, iqnis. I guess I screwed up in posting as a guest. I can't accept your answer from this account. I hope an upvote will suffice. Thanks again.